# How to have retractable limbs

Tags: modeling, rigging, extrude

I'm sure there are obvious tutorials for this but I didn't know how or what to google exactly so I'm asking here. How would I create and rig an object that has a limb or another piece of geometry that is normally hidden but that can extend from the object? I'd eventually like to have a perfect sphere most of the time but have the ability for the sphere to extrude hands and legs and have them function as a normal rig. I've attached a before and after cube, the after representing the arms and hands.

[image: No limb]

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89251/how-can-i-rig-telescopic-parts-to-move-one-at-a-time

Answer (score 2):

You could create your robot's basic armature, with all its limbs out. Parent the limbs bones to the body bone. When you'll parent the object to the armature, use the *With Empty Groups* mode then in *Object Data > Vertex Groups* assign each part of the mesh to the group it is supposed to be part of.

[image]

Then in the *Pose Library* save the basic pose and save a second pose that will be the contracted pose, here I've scaled my bones on the X axis. Click on the "+" button to save a pose:

[image]

Now whenever you want you can recall the contracted pose (select it and click on the magnifying glass icon of the *Pose Library*) and keyframe it in the *Dope Sheet*:

[image]